# Pass a datatable model to controller action in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Code:

```
@model System.Data.DataTable

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"> Download</button>



[HttpPost]
public void getCSV(DataTable dt)
{
   MemoryStream stream = Export.GetCSV(dt);

   var filename = "ExampleCSV.csv";
   var contenttype = "text/csv";
   Response.Clear();
   Response.ContentType = contenttype;
   Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
   Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
   Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
   Response.End();
}
```

I want to allow the user to export a CSV file when the button is clicked on. the datatable should be passed to the method getCSV. Please can someone help me. thanks

I do not mind using Tempdata to store the datatable and then access it in the controller

Comment: Instead of passing the `DataTable` I would recommend you just recreate it using the same method you use to create the initial model

Comment: musefan I cannot because the datatable is different each time the view in created.

Comment: OK, another option: When you create the DataTable for the model, you can store it in the session and reuse that in your getCSV method. If you insist on passing it via a post, then you need to have a form with fields that represent the database, and then build it based on those values - this could be painful depending on how complex your table is

Comment: Any other alternative to using the session? I don't mind using a different method then via post.

Comment: not really, you have to store it in memory somewhere. Whether that be in client memory and passed back in post, or in server memory stored in session (or an equivalent to session). But storing server side may not be good if you expect a lot of data, with a lot of different users doing it at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You want [FileStreamResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filestreamresult%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public FileStreamResult GetCSV(someType param)
{
   var dt = MyGetDt(param);
   MemoryStream stream = Export.GetCSV(dt);

   var filename = "ExampleCSV.csv";
   var contenttype = "text/csv";
   return new FileStreamResult(stream, contenttype)
   {FileDownloadName = filename};
}
```

Hope this helps!